# Error connecting to firebase 3 from Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Getting an error trying to connect to firebase 3 from Ionic app. The app's working fine and the new v3 config etc is fine, I'm sure the code is fine but I'm adding it below just incase.

I think it's my setup of firebase, Signin Method `Email/Password` is `enabled`. Do I need the plist file as suggested for the ios apps? The instructions are confusing as there's no specific ionic instructions, just ios, android and web.

Any suggestions as to how to move forward? ( Google seem to have made really complicated something that before was much simpler :( )

Thank you.

Here's my connection error (is there a way to get a better error than this?):

```
code: "auth/network-request-failed", message: "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."}
code
:
"auth/network-request-failed"
message
:
"A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."
```

Here's my config data in index.html

```
<script>
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: "myapikeymyapikeymyapikey",
    authDomain: "myapp.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "myapp.appspot.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Here's the firebase code in the app:

```
.factory('userService', function($rootScope, $window, $timeout, firebaseDBRef, firebaseAuthRef, firebaseUserRef, myStocksArrayService, myStocksCacheService, notesCacheService, modalService) {

  var login = function(user, signup) {
    var email = user.email;
    var password = user.password;

    firebaseAuthRef.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(function() {
        $rootScope.currentUser = authData;

        if(signup) {
          modalService.closeModal();
        }
        else {
          myStocksCacheService.removeAll();
          notesCacheService.removeAll();

          loadUserData(authData);

          modalService.closeModal();
          $timeout(function() {
            $window.location.reload(true);
          }, 400);
        }
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
        return false;
      });
  };

  var signup = function(user) {

    firebaseAuthRef.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
    .then(function(userData) {
      console.log(userData);
      login(user, true);
      firebaseDBRef.child('emails').push(user.email);
      firebaseUserRef.child(userData.uid).child('stocks').set(myStocksArrayService);

      var stocksWithNotes = notesCacheService.keys();

      stocksWithNotes.forEach(function(stockWithNotes) {
        var notes = notesCacheService.get(stockWithNotes);

        notes.forEach(function(note) {
          firebaseUserRef.child(userData.uid).child('notes').child(note.ticker).push(note);
        });
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("Error creating user:", error);
      return false;
    });
  };

  var logout = function() {
    firebaseAuthRef.signOut();
    notesCacheService.removeAll();
    myStocksCacheService.removeAll();
    $window.location.reload(true);
    $rootScope.currentUser = '';
  };

  var updateStocks = function(stocks) {
    firebaseUserRef.child(getUser().uid).child('stocks').set(stocks);
  };

  var updateNotes = function(ticker, notes) {
    firebaseUserRef.child(getUser().uid).child('notes').child(ticker).remove();
    notes.forEach(function(note) {
      firebaseUserRef.child(getUser().uid).child('notes').child(note.ticker).push(note);
    });
  };

  var loadUserData = function(authData) {

    firebaseUserRef.child(authData.uid).child('stocks').once('value', function(snapshot) {
      var stocksFromDatabase = [];

      snapshot.val().forEach(function(stock) {
        var stockToAdd = {ticker: stock.ticker};
        stocksFromDatabase.push(stockToAdd);
      });

      myStocksCacheService.put('myStocks', stocksFromDatabase);
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log("Firebase error –> stocks" + error);
    });

    firebaseUserRef.child(authData.uid).child('notes').once('value', function(snapshot) {

      snapshot.forEach(function(stocksWithNotes) {
        var notesFromDatabase = [];
        stocksWithNotes.forEach(function(note) {
          notesFromDatabase.push(note.val());
          var cacheKey = note.child('ticker').val();
          notesCacheService.put(cacheKey, notesFromDatabase);
        });
      });
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log("Firebase error –> notes: " + error);
    });
  };

  var getUser = function() {
    return firebaseAuthRef.currentUser;
  };

  if(getUser()) {
    $rootScope.currentUser = getUser();
  }

  return {
    login: login,
    signup: signup,
    logout: logout,
    updateStocks: updateStocks,
    updateNotes: updateNotes,
    getUser: getUser
  };
})
```

Comment: do you get the error on device?

Comment: On both the simulator and in chrome, not testing on a device.  It should work fine in both the simulator and chrome and it's not.

Answer (score 1):

You must add the plist! Don't you have it already?!

[image: its a file that will be downloaded when you add your app to firebase]

Then you have to add it to your app:

[image: you have to add it to your app]

NOTE; if you download it more than one time it will be showing with numbers (2) or (3) or (4) so delete these numbers at your xcode, the file name should be `GoogleService-Info.plist`. If it's anything else, it wont work.

Comment: What is 'plist'? Can you clarify your answer? This is rather unhelpful for future readers who happen upon this post.